# Check if all input fields are valid using js

Tags: javascript

I have an array called **formValues**, of objects that represent each input field. When user types in fields the objects get added to the array. 
So if no one types the array would be empty. 
I want a way to check if all fields which is always going to be 4 are valid and have a value thats not empty.

Here is the object that makes up each field.

```
[{{name:firstname, value:'fdfs', valid: true }}, next object... ]
```

I need a way to check if all fields are valid and have something in the value.

I was thinking something like the pseudo code below might work but not sure if there is a more efficient way or how to fully write it.

Creating an array of names of each input field. then mapping over them and trying to match the name to object name to see if its valid. 
What I have is close but I'm a bit stuck on that. 
Remember not all the objects will be in the formValues array until the type into each one so I need to check for that.

```
const allValid = names.map((name) => {
  return formValues that matches name must be valid and have a value length 
});
```

The function will run every time my React component updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's compose that into a few pieces:

1. "formValues that matches name"

   That's just:

   ```
   const item = formValues.find(item => item.name === name);
   // check that item is not undefined.
   ```
2. "must be valid and have a value length"

   ```
   item && item.valid && item.value.length > 0
   ```

So you can do something like:

```
const allValid = names.every(name => {
  const item = formValues.find(item => item.name === name);
  return item && item.valid && item.value.length > 0;
});
```

Comment: I like the idea but Item keeps returning undefined.

Comment: Try to use `console.log` or step and debug to see why this is the case. Might be a simple typo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency purposes, I'd reduce the form values to a map of a formValueName => formValue.

1. Reduce `formValues` to a map
2. Map each name to the corresponding form value (default to an empty object)
3. Check that all of the values are valid according to your definition, using [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Code:

```
const formValuesMap = formValues.reduce((init, curr) => 
    Object.assign(init, {[curr.name]: curr}), {});

const isAllValid = names
    .map(name => formValuesMap[name] || {})
    .every(({ valid, value }) => valid && value && value.length > 0);
```